# "sudo gem install bundler" throws error (Errno::EPERM)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

Recently my system was upgrader to macOS Sierra ( 10.12 ). When I try to install bundler gem, I am getting the below error.

Is it something to do with gem software / bundler / OS ?

```
$ sudo gem install bundler 
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
  Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
```

Please note that the user has the admin privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mac expert but it looks like maybe your OS is running rootless which you need to disable in order to use sudo. That being said, is there a reason you need to run sudo gem install? It's generally good to run gem install outside of sudo unless you know what you're doing and absolutely need the gem installed for all users.

That being said, if you need sudo you can try running `csrutil disable` in the command prompt and then rebooting and rerunning your `sudo gem install`.